# Dynamic change video.src HTML 5

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube

how to change video.src when watching a video

```
current = video.currentTime;
video.src = '2.mp4';
video.currentTime = current;
video.play();
```

Everything is working. But the video is interrupted for a moment.

How to change video without interrupting viewing. Youtube dynamically changes video with automatic quality change

Answer (score 0):

youTube uses something called Adaptive Streaming - a fragmented MP4 structure allows them to change quality up/down quickly and seamlessly because they are only loading content in very small chunks (about 2 seconds). If you want to do that, they you would need to look at a player that supports HLS or (better for the future) MPEG-DASH (eg [jwPlayer](https://www.jwplayer.com/video-solutions/adaptive-streaming/)) along with a suitable encoding solution (eg [Encoding.com](http://encoding.com))

If you want to change source to a new video seamlessly then the best way to do that is to have two video elements on the page, with the second source loaded, buffered, and paused (or update the currentTime to keep them in sync) and then when you want to switch toggle the visibility on the two video elements. There will still be a slight transition (especially if the two playheads are not in the same position).